# Is there an R function to create a Square sequence

Tags: r

I'm currently trying to grasp the basics of r. 
One Exercise I'm trying is creating square sequences where the sequence is the number squared itself.

I'm trying to create a sequence such as:

(1,2,3,4,5) = 
(1,2,9,64,625)

Is there a function for this in r?

Comment: `(1:5)^2` probably?

Comment: because i want the sequence 1 ^ 0, 2 ^ 1, 3 ^2  etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly understand what you want your desired output to be, but arrays are your friends. Almost anything you want to do here can be vectorized.

```
n <- 5
x <- seq(1:n)
x
y <- c(0:(n-1))
y
z <- x^y
z
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question is

```
(1:10) ^ (0:9)
```